# How to reopen closed stage from another thread in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a Java-application that looks like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    root.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml")));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1680, 1050);

    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();
    //some code
    stage.close();
    //normal java code in another class
}

public static void main(boolean first) {
    if (first) launch(new String[]{});
else{
//never prints hello, only hi
System.out.println("hi");
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello");
stage.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

My question is: What do I have to do to open fxml again from another class?
I tried to use Platform.runLater(), but it isn't working.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're probably getting an `IllegalStateException` with this code. When the last window is closed the JavaFX runtime exits and cannot be started again in the same JVM instance. If you don't want the JavaFX runtime to exit when the last window closes, use `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)`. Now you will have to explicitly call `Platform.exit()` to exit the runtime.

Comment: If I do as you suppose, I can't add controls to a JPanel running at the same time

Comment: Not sure I understand the conflict? Could you post a [mre] demonstrating the issue? Also, unless otherwise required, try to avoid mixing Swing and JavaFX in the same application (especially if you're starting a new project).